# Plot each predictor variable from multivariate GLM versus response (other predictors held constant)

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, glm

I can plot one predictor variable (from a mulitvariate logistic, binomial GLM) versus the predicted response.  I do it like this:

```
m3 <- mtcars # example with mtcars
model = glm(vs~cyl+mpg+wt+disp+drat,family=binomial, data=m3)
newdata <- m3
newdata$cyl <- mean(m3$cyl)
newdata$mpg <- mean(m3$mpg)
newdata$wt <- mean(m3$wt)
newdata$disp <- mean(m3$disp)
newdata$drat <- m3$drat
newdata$vs <- predict(model, newdata = newdata, type = "response")
ggplot(newdata, aes(x = drat, y = vs)) + geom_line()
```

Above, *drat* vs *vs* with all other predictors held constant.  However, I would to do this for each of the predictor variables, and doing the above process each time seems tedious.  Is there a smarter way to do this? I'd like to visualize the response of each the different predictors and eventually, perhaps, at different constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the response.plot2 function in the biomod2 package. It was developed to create response curves for species distribution models but it essentially does what you need- it generates a multi pannel plot with responses for each variable used in your model. It also outputs the data into a data structure that can then be used to plot in whichever way you like.